# Can we add bosonic phonon in the Standard Model of Particles?

Tags: particle-physics, acoustics, standard-model, bosons, phonons

Nowadays, we describe phonon as “particle” of sound. They have zero spin but are thought to have mass and kinetic energy.

Phonons are the smallest units of the vibrational energy that makes up sound waves —> the same way that photons makes up the intensity of electromagnetic waves.  Also, just as photon is a boson (gauge boson of light), phonon is bosonic as they describe the quantitative deviation of a collection of atomic nuclei from their equilibrium (i.e., their average nucleic position).

Phonons do not have all the ingredients required in the Standard Model (local symmetry, three fermion generations, scalar multiplet, SSB).  Is this the reason why phonon are not in the boson list of SM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Phonons do not have all the ingredients required in the Standard Model (local symmetry, three fermion generations, scalar multiplet, SSB). Is this the reason why phonon are not in the boson list of SM?

The table of particles axiomatically assumed for [the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) consists of point elementary particles, i.e.non  composite. Phonons by the your  description  are composite excitations. Notice that not even protons are counted as elementary particles in the table.

Comment: Thank you for citing this out.  If a phonon is composite, do we know what make up a phonon?

Comment: I copy from you "phonon is bosonic as they describe the quantitative deviation of a collection of atomic nuclei from their equilibrium (i.e., their average nucleic position)." . It takes many nuclei vibrating to make one phonon. from your description. It cannot be a "point" particle.

Comment: Thanks again.  Engineers/scientists should be more forthright in describing phonon as quasi particle instead of saying "particle" to avoid confusion (as I was).